# RegExp: select space if space exists

Tags: c#, regex

I got values like

```
\w{1,2}-\w{1,2}\d{1,4} and \w{1,2}-\w{1,2} \d{1,4}
```

I transform these values:

```
AB-CD 1 -> AB-CD1
AB-CD1 -> AB-CD1
```

I do it using

```
[ ]{1}[\d]{1}
```

and replacing " " to "". This works well.

But now I need to do the following transformation:

```
AB-CD1 -> AB-CD 1
AB-CD 1 -> AB-CD 1
```

I tried a look ahead aiming any digit

```
(?=\d)
```

but then I get two spaces if my text already contains one. I need to select the space (or none) between \w and \d - how do I do that?

Comment: What language is this in? (I ask because many flavors of regex support lookbehind, `(?<! )`, while many do not.)

Comment: Also: I hope you're aware that `\w` matches digits (not just letters and underscores), that `[\d]` is equivalent to `\d`, and that `{1}` is redundant?

Comment: It's C# dialect. And yes it may be redundant but I find that more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write:

```
(?<![\d ]) ?(?=\d)
```

to match an optional space (i.e., either a space or the empty string) position that does *not* follow a digit or space and *does* precede a digit.

(`(?<!...)` is a *negative lookbehind assertion*; see http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.)

Comment: I want to select the space or an empty string if there is no space between character and digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `([^\d ])(?=\d)` with **"\1 "**.

Answer (score 0):

don't know c#.. but you may try replace:

```
([a-zA-Z])([0-9]+)
```

to `\1 \2`

a small test with sed:

```
kent$  echo "AB-CD1"|sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z])([0-9]+)/\1 \2/g'
AB-CD 1
```